# devbridge autocomplete howto empty search field

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, autocomplete

The text field is for adding tags to a post. If there's no proper task, there should be a possibility to add another tag. 
I didn't find a possibility to do this via the "noSuggestionNotice" - so I'm sending via AJAX also the data "add 'input from searchfield' as new hashtag" in my AJAX search method
But when I select this entry, the text field stays "add 'input from searchfield' as new hashtag" - this looks strange and the new suggestion when You click on the field is "add 'add 'input from searchfield' as new hashtag' as new hashtag"
Is there a possibility to empty the search field?
Here's the js-code:

```
$('#appbundle_blog_post_additionalOtherTag').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '{{ path('post_othertag_search') }}',
    paramName: 'otherTag',
    triggerSelectOnValidInput: false,
    minChars: 3,
    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
    noSuggestionNotice: 'Keine Tags vorhanden!',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        {# load suggestions #}
        $.post('{{ path('post_othertag_add', {'id':post.id}) }}', { name: suggestion.value, otherId: suggestion.data })
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#otherTags').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                console.log('Fehler:');
                console.log(data);
            });
    }
}).onclick($('#appbundle_blog_post_additionalOtherTag').empty());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out by myself. Seems this is basic jquery knowledge.

```
$('#appbundle_blog_post_additionalOtherTag').val("");
```

So the full script is:

```
$('#appbundle_blog_post_additionalOtherTag').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '{{ path('post_othertag_search') }}',
    paramName: 'otherTag',
    triggerSelectOnValidInput: false,
    minChars: 3,
    showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
    noSuggestionNotice: 'Keine Tags vorhanden!',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        {# load suggestions #}
        $.post('{{ path('post_othertag_add', {'id':post.id}) }}', { name: suggestion.value, otherId: suggestion.data })
            .done(function (data) {
                $('#otherTags').html(data);
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                console.log('Fehler:');
                console.log(data);
            });
        $('#appbundle_blog_post_additionalOtherTag').val("");
    }
});
```